# Check if DrawableRes is VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have a method that's setting VectorDrawable as DrawableLeft, DrawableRight, etc. on TextView and Button, but I would like to make it work also for normal Drawable. So, is there a way to check the type of DrawableRes, or should I use try/catch? 
The method looks like this:

```
public static void setViewDrawables(@NonNull View view, @DrawableRes int left, @DrawableRes int top, @DrawableRes int right, @DrawableRes int bottom) {
    final Resources resources = view.getResources();
    Drawable vectorDrawableLeft = left != 0 ? VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, left, view.getContext().getTheme()) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableTop = top != 0 ? VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, top, view.getContext().getTheme()) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableRight = right != 0 ? VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, right, view.getContext().getTheme()) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableBottom = bottom != 0 ? VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, bottom, view.getContext().getTheme()) : null;

    if (view instanceof Button) {
        ((Button) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(vectorDrawableLeft, vectorDrawableTop, vectorDrawableRight, vectorDrawableBottom);
    }
    else if (view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(vectorDrawableLeft, vectorDrawableTop, vectorDrawableRight, vectorDrawableBottom);
    } else {
        Log.e("ERROR: ViewUtils", "Can't do setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds on " + view.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want `android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources
`?

Comment: It's working. Thanks! I just replaced `VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, left, view.getContext().getTheme())` with `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), left)`.

Comment: there is also `android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat
` but i dont know if it works as well, you can check it out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up comments to an answer. As far as I have found there is no easy way to know if DrawableRes is pointing to VectorDrawable or not. If someone knows how, please write. But to solve my problem it was enough to use `android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources` as @pskink suggested. So now method looks like:

```
public static void setViewDrawables(@NonNull View view, @DrawableRes int left, @DrawableRes int top, @DrawableRes int right, @DrawableRes int bottom) {
    Drawable vectorDrawableLeft = left != 0 ? AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), left) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableTop = top != 0 ? AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), top) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableRight = right != 0 ? AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), right) : null;
    Drawable vectorDrawableBottom = bottom != 0 ? AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), bottom) : null;

    if (view instanceof Button) {
        ((Button) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(vectorDrawableLeft, vectorDrawableTop, vectorDrawableRight, vectorDrawableBottom);
    } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(vectorDrawableLeft, vectorDrawableTop, vectorDrawableRight, vectorDrawableBottom);
    } else {
        Log.e("ERROR: ViewUtils", "Can't do setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds on " + view.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

**Update:**

In `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager` there is a method `boolean isVectorDrawable(@NonNull Drawable d)` which is checking if Drawable is VectorDrawable, but it's taking Drawable as an argument, and not DrawableRes. It looks like this:

```
private static boolean isVectorDrawable(@NonNull Drawable d) {
    return d instanceof VectorDrawableCompat
          || PLATFORM_VD_CLAZZ.equals(d.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: if you want to know how they did it, simple step-in into `AppCompatResources.getDrawable` with your debugger and check when/how they call `VectorDrawableCompat.create` when `VectorDrawableCompat` has to be created

Comment: just couple of lines after `isVectorDrawable` method there is `private static class VdcInflateDelegate implements InflateDelegate` which inflates `VectorDrawableCompat` object

Comment: @pskink Yes, but as you can see it's a try/catch approach, and I asked in the question is there any other cleaner way to do it. In that method, they are trying to create VectorDrawable, and if it's not working then it's not VectorDrawable.

Comment: no, debug method `loadDrawableFromDelegates`, just after `String tagName = parser.getName()`

Comment: so in short: they first check if the resource name ends with `xml` and if it does they are trying to get the root element, then if it is `"vector"` they call `VectorDrawableCompat.create` method